# Refer to calculate field in VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

In my front end DB I have a query "QryAcompanhamento" which has a calculated field "CalcAlerta" which has the following expression:

> CalcAlerta: IIF((Date()>([Data_Vencimento]-5)) And is Null([Pag_Data-ProgPag]);"Crítico";IIF((Date()>([Data_Vencimento]-10)) And is null([Pag_Data-ProgPag]);"Urgente";""))

The calculated field works perfectly.

My front end also has a Continuous Form where I do some filtering stuff.

I've inserted a ComboBox in this form named boxAlerta and a button with the following code:

```
Private Sub Comando254_Click()  
...  
 Dim boxAlerta as String  
...  
Alerta = "[CalcAlerta] = " & [boxAlerta] & ""  
...  
ElseIf Me.boxAlerta <> "" Then  
    Me.Filter = Alerta  
    Me.FilterOn = True  
End If
```

When I click the button, it should filter the form showing only the values in the comboBox.

I also Have another of this code but that's not calculated field and works perfectly. i only get error when it's a calculated field.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind!

I used the following code and it works:

```
Alerta = "[CalcAlerta] = " & "'" & Me.boxAlerta & "'"
```

How it helps someone!